# zsh completes the full HostName instead of the short one

Tags: ssh, zsh

In my `~/.ssh/config` I have

```
Host students
    HostName students.foo.edu.pl
    User bar
```

Then, when trying to complete `ssh stu`, zsh suggests `students.foo.edu.pl` instead of `students`.

On the other hand, the autocompletion works properly, when an IP address is used:

```
Host knl
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User usrxxx
    Port 7777
```

Why? How can I fix it? Relevant parts of my `.zshrc` (omitting prompt and history configuration)

```
setopt nomatch
bindkey -e

#Completion
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

#Needed for colorful prompts
autoload -U colors && colors
setopt promptsubst
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE

#Antigen
source /usr/share/zsh/scripts/antigen/antigen.zsh
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
antigen bundle olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt
```

Neither of the hosts has been defined in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

It has surely found this host in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Delete the corresponding line of `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, after connecting to this host a couple of times, the problem reappers.

Comment: You can hash your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with the parameter `    HashKnownHosts yes` on `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. This feature secured your file and block autocomplete host from this file